# A Oscillatory integral in light-cone coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, integration, propagator, regularization

I am trying to evaluate an integral in light-cone coordinates
Where light-cone coordinates in 1+1D are defined by
$x^+=\frac{x^0+x^1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $x^-=\frac{x^0-x^1}{\sqrt 2}$.

The integral that I need to evaluate is
$$\int dk^+dk^-e^{-\imath k\cdot x}\frac{1}{-2k^+k^-},$$  can have any method to do it,
If not can we do the definite integral that $k^+$ and $k^-$ vary from $-\infty \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Why not  change the integration variables to the standard non-lightcone ones? Then
$$
I= \int dk^0dk_0e^{i(k_1x^1-k_0x^0)}\frac 1{k_0^2-k_1^2},
$$
is $(2\pi)^2$  times the usual  massless scalar-field propagator. You need an $i\epsilon$ prescription, and an infra-red regulator to get an unique answer. You can then change  the $x^i$ variables back to the  $x^\pm$

Comment: In standard none light-cone coordinates, we need a regulator to do the job, can we do it without using any regulator in light-cone coordinates?

Comment: No. It's exactly the same integral. Changing the integration variables  changes nothing.